# USB mouse stopped after installing all packages!

Tags: drivers, mouse

i installed Synaptic then marked & installed almost all of its packages. But my USB mouse has stopped working. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: You installed ALL packages out there? Seriously?

Comment: What packages did you install? Could provide more details? Your question lacks any useful information.

Comment: Yes, I installed all. now how can I find their list and what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed ALL packages out there, the chance of having conflicts is probably over a 100% several ten times over, which is likely to be the cause of your issue.

Undoing installs is a bit cumbersome. To find all the packages you installed (many thousands probably), do `tail -n4 /var/log/apt/history.log`. The third line contains all the package you last installed. You're going to have to uninstall all these. For that we're going to need some shell magic.

First of all, save the list of packages to a file:

`tail -n 4 /var/log/apt/history.log | grep Install | tr ',' '\n' > ~/packages.log`

Then, we're going to have to uninstall them all. I'm using a few keywords to sanitize the list of packages. This works on my machine, but your mileage may vary.

**ONLY** do the following when you know you want to remove all the stuff you previously installed

```
for i in `cat ~/packages.log | cut -d ':' -f1 | grep -v Install | grep -v automatic`; do sudo apt-get purge $i; done;
```

Followed by:  `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean up more.

Comment: No, they are all less than 40, and I shall  keep some of them. How can I remove them individually?